# Give customized border to mat-card

Tags: css, angular-material

I am trying to give a customized border to mat-card but I'm unable to do so.I am using ng-deep to style the mat-card.I am able to get rounded border with border radius but no colored border is visible.I don't know what am I missing.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Below is my css:

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-card{

    border: 55px !important;
    border-radius: 30px !important;
    border: #000 !important;
   }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have CSS issue,
you are setting `border: 55px !important;` then override it with `border: #000 !important;`.

You should use: `border: 55px solid #000`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following class in **mat-card**.

```
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z0">
contents...............
<mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the radius of the mat-card just set this CSS property
and just change the number. It should work.

```
border-radius: var(--mdc-elevated-card-container-shape, var(--mdc-shape-medium, 16px))
```